# overcome Graphdef cannot be larger than 2GB in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow's [imageNet trained model](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet) to extract the last pooling layer's features as representation vectors for a new dataset of images.

The model as is predicts on a new image as follows:

```
python classify_image.py --image_file new_image.jpeg
```

I edited the main function so that I can take a folder of images and return the prediction on all images at once and write the feature vectors in a csv file. Here is how I did that:

```
def main(_):
  maybe_download_and_extract()
  #image = (FLAGS.image_file if FLAGS.image_file else
  #         os.path.join(FLAGS.model_dir, 'cropped_panda.jpg'))
  #edit to take a directory of image files instead of a one file
  if FLAGS.data_folder:
    images_folder=FLAGS.data_folder
    list_of_images = os.listdir(images_folder)
  else: 
    raise ValueError("Please specify image folder")

  with open("feature_data.csv", "wb") as f:
    feature_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|')

    for image in list_of_images:
      print(image) 
      current_features = run_inference_on_image(images_folder+"/"+image)
      feature_writer.writerow([image]+current_features)
```

It worked just fine for around 21 images but then crashed with the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1912, in as_graph_def
    raise ValueError("GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.")
ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.
```

I thought by calling the method `run_inference_on_image(images_folder+"/"+image)` the previous image data would be overwritten to only consider the new image data, which doesn't seem to be the case. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem here is that each call to `run_inference_on_image()` *adds* nodes to the same graph, which eventually exceeds the maximum size. There are at least two ways to fix this:

1. The **easy but slow** way is to use a different default graph for each call to `run_inference_on_image()`:

   ```
   for image in list_of_images:
     # ...
     with tf.Graph().as_default():
       current_features = run_inference_on_image(images_folder+"/"+image)
     # ...
   ```
2. The **more involved but more efficient** way is to modify `run_inference_on_image()` to run on multiple images. Relocate your `for` loop to surround [this `sess.run()` call](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3c8780451007c27b69f10925d43d1f3501d94106/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet/classify_image.py#L171), and you will no longer have to reconstruct the entire model on each call, which should make processing each image much faster.

Comment: I went with the second option and it's faster. Thanks for idea!

Comment: one question though, is there a way to pass an array of images instead of only one in the prediction part of the sess.run ```predictions = sess.run(pool_3_tensor,
                           {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})```

Comment: I think that particular feed point only works on a single image. It would be possible to change the graph so that it took a batch of images, but this would require creating a prefetching thread (using e.g. `tf.train.batch()`) to combine the images into a batch (which would have to all have the same size), and then feed into a slightly later point in the network. You would have to use the `input_map` argument to `tf.import_graph_def()` to change the tensor that is used as input. Since the structure of that particular graph is undocumented, it might be challenging though...

Comment: Hello, can you explain what do you mean by surround the sess.run call? i've tried many different variations but i still run into the same error. thanks! :)

Comment: I just mean "call that instance of `sess.run()` in a for loop". You'll have to restructure things somewhat so that you have the list of images to loop over, but it shouldn't be too hard to change.

Comment: @mrry For training a model, I have `tf.global_variables_initializer()` followed by a for loop to iterate through training data, within `with tf.Session() as sess`.
How can I move the for loop out of `sess.run()` without reinitializing the variables in every iteration?

Comment: @user3620605 This should probably be a new question... the comments format isn't well suited to describing code structure!

Comment: @mrry  I'm having trouble with the second method -- I made a new thread.
If you have time can you please take a look --
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819088/overcome-graphdef-cannot-be-larger-than-2gb-in-tensorflow-image-transformatio

Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

You can move the `create_graph()` to somewhere *before* this loop `for image in list_of_images:` (which loops over files).

What it does is performing inference multiple times on the same graph.

Comment: can you show an example of this for clarity? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is put `create_graph()` at the first of main function.
Then, it just create graph only

Answer (score 0):

A good explanation of why such errors is mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5383), I encountered the same error while using tf dataset api and came to the understanding that data when iterated over in the session, its getting appended on the existing graph. so what I did is used `tf.reset_default_graph()` before the dataset iterator to make sure that previous graph is cleared away.

Hope this helps for such a scenario.