# Tensorflow save model: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow

I'm getting the following error -- apparently at the time of saving my model

```
Step = 1799  |  Tensorflow Accuracy = 1.0
Step = 1799  |  My Accuracy = 0.0363355780022
Step = 1800  |  Tensorflow Accuracy = 1.0
Step = 1800  |  My Accuracy = 0.0364694929089
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CNN-LSTM-seg-reg-sigmoid.py", line 290, in <module>
    saver.save(sess, save_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1085, in save
    self.export_meta_graph(meta_graph_filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1103, in export_meta_graph
    add_shapes=True),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2175, in as_graph_def
    result, _ = self._as_graph_def(from_version, add_shapes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2138, in _as_graph_def
    raise ValueError("GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.")
ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.
```

[Here](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/StRWYvb68T4) suggested to look out for `tf.constant`s, but I have zero constants in my program. However, my `weights` and `biases` are like the following: `tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32]),name="bc1")`. Could this be an issue?

If not that, than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349049/overcome-graphdef-cannot-be-larger-than-2gb-in-tensorflow) tells me that somewhere I am adding to the graph after every loop iteration, but I'm unsure where it is occuring.

My first guess is when I make predictions. I make predictions via the 
following code...

```
# Make prediction
im = Image.open('/home/volcart/Documents/Data/input_crops/temp data0001.tif')
batch_x = np.array(im)
batch_x = batch_x.reshape((1, n_input_x, n_input_y))
batch_x = batch_x.astype(float)
prediction = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: batch_x})
prediction = tf.sigmoid(prediction.reshape((n_input_x * n_input_y, n_classes)))
prediction = prediction.eval().reshape((n_input_x, n_input_y, n_classes))
```

My second guess is when I calculate `loss` and `accuracy` via the following: `loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})`

My entire session code looks like the following:

```
# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions()
config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    summary = tf.train.SummaryWriter('/tmp/logdir/', sess.graph) #initialize graph for tensorboard
    step = 1
    # Import data
    data = scroll_data.read_data('/home/volcart/Documents/Data/')
    # Keep training until reach max iterations
    while step * batch_size < training_iters:
        batch_x, batch_y = data.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        # Run optimization op (backprop)
        batch_x = batch_x.reshape((batch_size, n_input_x, n_input_y))
        batch_y = batch_y.reshape((batch_size, n_input_x, n_input_y))
        batch_y = convert_to_2_channel(batch_y, batch_size)
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        step = step + 1

        loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                          y: batch_y})


        # Make prediction
        im = Image.open('/home/volcart/Documents/Data/input_crops/temp data0001.tif')
        batch_x = np.array(im)
        batch_x = batch_x.reshape((1, n_input_x, n_input_y))
        batch_x = batch_x.astype(float)
        prediction = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: batch_x})
        prediction = tf.sigmoid(prediction.reshape((n_input_x * n_input_y, n_classes)))
        prediction = prediction.eval().reshape((n_input_x, n_input_y, n_classes))

        # Temp arrays are to splice the prediction n_input_x x n_input_y x 2
            # into 2 matrices n_input_x x n_input_y
        temp_arr1 = np.empty((n_input_x, n_input_y))
        for i in xrange(n_input_x):
            for j in xrange(n_input_x):
                for k in xrange(n_classes):
                    if k == 0:
                        temp_arr1[i][j] = 1 - prediction[i][j][k]

        my_acc = accuracy_custom(temp_arr1,batch_y[0,:,:,0])

        print "Step = " + str(step) + "  |  Tensorflow Accuracy = " + str(acc)
        print "Step = " + str(step) + "  |  My Accuracy = " + str(my_acc)

        if step % 100 == 0:
            save_path = "/home/volcart/Documents/CNN-LSTM-reg-model/CNN-LSTM-seg-step-" + str(step) + "-model.ckpt"
            saver.save(sess, save_path)
            csv_file = "/home/volcart/Documents/CNN-LSTM-reg/CNNLSTMreg-step-" + str(step) + "-accuracy-" + str(my_acc) + ".csv"
            np.savetxt(csv_file, temp_arr1, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: does it crash immediately? try to save at each step. if it crashes after few steps then something is wrong with the model.

Answer (score 2):

You are growing your graph at this line:

```
prediction = tf.sigmoid(prediction.reshape((n_input_x * n_input_y, n_classes)))
```

This converts your `prediction` numpy array to TensorFlow constant node, inlines it into the Graph, and adds `Sigmoid` node on top of that.

You can catch problems like this by adding `tf.get_default_graph().finalize()` before starting your training loop

Comment: If I use `tf.get_default_graph().finalize()` then I am unable to add new nodes such as the line that is causing the issue. Will I need to create a node before `Session` and do a `sess.run()`? With that particular node?

Comment: All the Tensorflow nodes can (and should) be defined before starting the session to avoid errors like yours

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the below line of your code utilizing the tf.placeholder:

prediction = tf.sigmoid(prediction.reshape((n_input_x * n_input_y, n_classes)))

this will solve the issue.