# Does anyone know how to allocate more memory for the graph? Tensorflow: "ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB."

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

I am learning how to do transfer learning from an already trained AlexNet on images. I am striping off the last fully connected layer in AlexNet and creating my own layer with the number of classes in my traffic signs labels. I don't want to retrain the layers previous to this new layer only the new layer itself.

I am having trouble finding the bug that is causing this error. I have searched the web for solutions, but I don't believe any of them apply.

Please take a moment and see if you can find where I am creating the extra nodes that are causing the Graph to grow. Thanks!

```
import pickle
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from alexnet import AlexNet
import os
import numpy as np

# TODO: Load traffic signs data.
# Load pickled data
# Where training and testing data is saved.
training_file = os.getcwd()+"/train.p"
print(training_file)

with open(training_file, mode='rb') as f:
    train = pickle.load(f)



X_train, y_train = train['features'], train['labels']
print('Train data shape = ', X_train.shape)  

X_train_original = np.copy(X_train)


# TODO: Split data into training and validation sets.

X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train, 
                                                      y_train, 
                                                      train_size=.8, 
                                                      random_state=42)


# TODO: Define placeholders and resize operation.
nb_classes = 43
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 32, 32, 3), name='x')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None), name='y')
one_hot_y = tf.one_hot(y, 43, name='one_hot_y')
resized = tf.image.resize_images(x, (227, 227))
print('Resized data shape = ', resized.shape)  

# TODO: pass placeholder as first argument to `AlexNet`.
fc7 = AlexNet(resized, feature_extract=True)
# NOTE: `tf.stop_gradient` prevents the gradient from flowing backwards
# past this point, keeping the weights before and up to `fc7` frozen.
# This also makes training faster, less work to do!
fc7 = tf.stop_gradient(fc7)

# TODO: Add the final layer for traffic sign classification.

shape = (fc7.get_shape().as_list()[-1], nb_classes) # use this shape for the weight matrix

#fc8W = np.random.normal(0, .15, size=(shape[0], shape[1])).astype(np.float32)
#print(fc8W)
#fc8b = np.random.normal(0, .15, size=(shape[1])).astype(np.float32)
#print(fc8b)

mu = 0
sigma = 0.05
fc8W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=1e-2))
fc8b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(nb_classes))

#logits = tf.matmul(fc7, fc8W) + fc8b; print(logits)
logits = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(fc7, fc8W, fc8b)
#probs = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

# TODO: Define loss, training, accuracy operations.
# HINT: Look back at your traffic signs project solution, you may
# be able to reuse some the code.
rate = 0.001
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=one_hot_y)
loss_operation = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = rate)
training_operation = optimizer.minimize(loss_operation)

# TODO: Train and evaluate the feature extraction model.


#Shuffle data
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)

#Epochs for training and batch sizes defined.
EPOCHS = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 128

### Evaluation function.
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(one_hot_y, 1))
accuracy_operation = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
#saver = tf.train.Saver()

def evaluate(X_data, y_data):
    num_examples = len(X_data)
    total_accuracy = 0
    sess = tf.get_default_session()
    for offset in range(0, num_examples, BATCH_SIZE):
        batch_x, batch_y = X_data[offset:offset+BATCH_SIZE], y_data[offset:offset+BATCH_SIZE]
        accuracy = sess.run(accuracy_operation, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, keep_prob: 1})
        total_accuracy += (accuracy * len(batch_x))
    return total_accuracy / num_examples

### Training function.
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    num_examples = len(X_train)

    print("Training...")
    print()
    for i in range(EPOCHS):
        X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)
        for offset in range(0, num_examples, BATCH_SIZE):
            end = offset + BATCH_SIZE
            batch_x, batch_y = X_train[offset:end], y_train[offset:end]
            sess.run(training_operation, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

        train_accuracy = evaluate(X_train, y_train)
        validation_accuracy = evaluate(X_valid, y_valid)
        print("EPOCH {} ...".format(i+1))
        print('Training Accuracy = {:.3f}'.format(train_accuracy))
        print("Validation Accuracy = {:.3f}".format(validation_accuracy))
        print()
```

Comment: Okay I found the cause for this error. 'logits' was misspelled as 'logtis'. Now I have a new error. 'GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.' Is there a way to reduce the graph size?

Comment: Update your question with the code modified as it is now and post the error, or open a new question please.

Comment: Seems related, can you check:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349049/overcome-graphdef-cannot-be-larger-than-2gb-in-tensorflow

Comment: I did check that first before posting. I don't believe that applies in my case. If it does, I don't see it. Thanks.