# Tensorflow: Number of nodes in the graph keeps increasing as training goes on

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training a convolutional model in tensorflow. After training the model for about 70 epochs, which took almost 1.5 hrs, I couldn't save the model. It gave me `ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB`. I found that as the training proceeds the number of nodes in my graph keeps increasing.

At epochs 0,3,6,9, the number of nodes in the graph are 7214, 7238, 7262, 7286 respectively. When I use `with tf.Session() as sess:`, instead of passing the session as `sess = tf.Session()`, the number of nodes are 3982, 4006, 4030, 4054 at epochs 0,3,6,9 respectively.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36358913/3620605) answer, it is said that as nodes get added to the graph, it can exceed its maximum size. I need help with understanding how the number of nodes keep going up in my graph.

I train my model using the code below:

```
def runModel(data):
    '''
    Defines cost, optimizer functions, and runs the graph
    '''
    X, y,keep_prob = modelInputs((755, 567, 1),4)
    logits = cnnModel(X,keep_prob)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y), name="cost")
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(.0001).minimize(cost)
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1), name="correct_pred")
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32), name='accuracy')

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    for e in range(12):
        batch_x, batch_y = data.next_batch(30)
        x = tf.reshape(batch_x, [30, 755, 567, 1]).eval(session=sess)
        batch_y = tf.one_hot(batch_y,4).eval(session=sess)
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, y: batch_y,keep_prob:0.5})
        if e%3==0:
            n = len([n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node])
            print("No.of nodes: ",n,"\n")
            current_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: x, y: batch_y,keep_prob:1.0})
            acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: x, y: batch_y,keep_prob:1.0})
            print("At epoch {epoch:>3d}, cost is {a:>10.4f}, accuracy is {b:>8.5f}".format(epoch=e, a=current_cost, b=acc))
```

What causes an increase in the number of nodes?

Comment: Maybe you could get the names of the new nodes at each step, and see which nodes they are ? Maybe it's just the input nodes that get copied everytime, I have no idea... What version of tf are you using ?

Comment: @gdelab I'm using `1.0.1`, the number of nodes seems to be increasing by 8 for every epoch!

Comment: Yes, but could you get the eight new node names at each step ? Maybe they can help understand where new nodes are created...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating new nodes within your training loop. In particular, you are calling `tf.reshape` and `tf.one_hot`, each of which creates one (or more) nodes. You can either:

- Create those nodes outside of the graph using placeholders as inputs, and then only evaluate them in the loop.
- Not use TensorFlow for those operations and use instead NumPy or equivalent operations.

I would recommend the second one, since there does not seem to be any benefit in using TensorFlow for data preparation. You can have something like:

```
import numpy as np
# ...
    x = np.reshape(batch_x, [30, 755, 567, 1])
    # ...
    # One way of doing one-hot encoding with NumPy
    classes_arr = np.arange(4).reshape([1] * batch_y.ndims + [-1])
    batch_y = (np.expand_dims(batch_y, -1) == classes_arr).astype(batch_y.dtype)
    # ...
```

PD: I'd also recommend using `tf.Session()` in a `with` [context manager](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/) to make sure its `close()` method is called at the end (unless you want to keep using the same session later).

Answer (score 0):

Another option, that solved a similar problem for me, is to use `tf.reset_default_graph()`