# overcome Graphdef cannot be larger than 2GB in tensorflow -- Image transformations with tf

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I've referred to this question, but I don't quite understand the
second method provided by Mr.mrry.

[overcome Graphdef cannot be larger than 2GB in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349049/overcome-graphdef-cannot-be-larger-than-2gb-in-tensorflow)

Basically, I'm trying to use tf's built in image transformation methods on images. I'm running into the error provided in the title. 
Also, do I need to keep creating a new session for each iteration?
Currently, this process is a little slow and am not sure how to speed it up.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from scipy.ndimage import imread
from scipy.misc import imresize, imshow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


for fish in Fishes:
    fish_images = os.listdir(os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Moondra\\Desktop\\Fishes', fish))  # get the image files
    os.makedirs(SAVE_DIR + fish, exist_ok = True)
    for num, fish_image in enumerate(fish_images):
        image =imread(os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Moondra\\Desktop\\Fishes', fish, fish_image))
        new_img =tf.image.adjust_brightness(image, .4)  #image transformation
        with tf.Session() as sess:

            new_image =sess.run(new_img)
            imsave(os.path.join(SAVE_DIR, fish, fish +str(num)+'.jpg'), new_image)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how TF should be used.

1. You should create graph **once**.
2. You should create session **once**.

Your current code does both things in a loop, thus causing slowness and memory issues. The problem lies in the fact that TF is not imperative language, so

```
new_img =tf.image.adjust_brightness(image, .4)  #image transformation
```

is not application of a function on the image.This creates an operation in a graph, and stores reference to this operation in new_img. So each time you call this function, your graph grows.

So in pseudo code it should be:

```
create placeholder for image name
create transformed image op - new_img
create session
for each image
  call in a session new_img op, providing path to the placehodler using feed_dict
```