# Tensorflow Loss and accuracy error Neural Network

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, mnist

Hope you are in good health. Actually I am facing a problem in my self built code. I am a beginner in Machine Learning and working on neural network. I build my own neural network and trying to train dataset with the help of tensorflow but getting alot of loss and having some problem with printing my accuracy Please view the code Thank you!

**Here is my code I implement it on kaggle:**

```
# This Python 3 environment comes with many helpful analytics libraries installed
# It is defined by the kaggle/python docker image: https://github.com/kaggle/docker-python
# For example, here's several helpful packages to load in 

import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
from subprocess import check_output
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf
# Input data files are available in the "../input/" directory.
# For example, running this (by clicking run or pressing Shift+Enter) will list the files in the input directory

import os
print(os.listdir("../input"))
print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('../input',one_hot=True)
x_train=mnist.train.images
y_train=mnist.train.labels
x_test=mnist.test.images 
y_test=mnist.test.labels


# Any results you write to the current directory are saved as output.

layer1_neuron=500
layer2_neuron=500
layer3_neuron=500
number_of_class=10
batch_size=200
x=tf.placeholder('float',[None,784]) #28 * 28 is 784 (shape of the data)
y=tf.placeholder('float')
    #my neural network   

def neural_network(x_train):
    hidden_layer_1={
        'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784,layer1_neuron])),
        'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer1_neuron]))
         }
    hidden_layer_2={
        'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer1_neuron,layer2_neuron])),
        'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer2_neuron]))
        }
    hidden_layer_3={
        'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer2_neuron,layer3_neuron])),
        'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer3_neuron]))
        }
    output={
        'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer3_neuron,number_of_class])),
        'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([number_of_class]))
        }

    l1=tf.add(tf.matmul(x_train,hidden_layer_1['weights']),hidden_layer_1['biases'])
    l1=tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2=tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_layer_2['weights']),hidden_layer_2['biases'])
    l2=tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3=tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_layer_3['weights']),hidden_layer_3['biases'])
    l3=tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output=tf.add(tf.matmul(l3,output['weights']),output['biases'])

    return output


    # for splitting out batches of data
def next_batch(num, data, labels):
    idx = np.arange(0 , len(data))
    np.random.shuffle(idx)
    idx = idx[:num]
    data_shuffle = [data[ i] for i in idx]
    labels_shuffle = [labels[ i] for i in idx]

    return np.asarray(data_shuffle), np.asarray(labels_shuffle)


def traning_neuralNetwork(x_test,x_train,y_test,y_train):
    total_epochs=5
    total_loss=0
    epoch_loss=0
    batch_size=200
    num_batch = int(np.ceil(42000/batch_size))
    prediction=[]
    prediction=neural_network(x_train)
    cost=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction,labels=y_train))
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range (total_epochs):
            epoch_loss=0
            for _ in range (num_batch):
                x_train,y_train=next_batch(batch_size,x_train,y_train)
                _,epoch_loss=sess.run([optimizer,cost],feed_dict={x:x_train,y:y_train})
                total_loss+=epoch_loss
            print('Epoch ',epoch, " loss = ",total_loss)

        print("Traning Complete!")
        correct=tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
        accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct,'float'))
        print('accuracy',accuracy.eval({x : x_test,y : y_test}))




traning_neuralNetwork(x_test,x_train,y_test,y_train)
```

**Output Error**

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-3-92b45e11aa74>:61: softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:

Future major versions of TensorFlow will allow gradients to flow
into the labels input on backprop by default.

See tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2.

Epoch  0  loss =  968685.6919555664
Epoch  1  loss =  1076421.9005126953
Epoch  2  loss =  1108946.4575500488
Epoch  3  loss =  1117600.8527259827
Epoch  4  loss =  1119452.7342455387
Traning Complete!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1329     try:
-> 1330       return fn(*args)
   1331     except errors.OpError as e:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1314       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1315           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1316 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1422             self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1423             status, run_metadata)
   1424 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    515             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 516             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    517     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [55000] vs. [10000]
     [[Node: Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](ArgMax, ArgMax_1)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6ce6d479d3df> in <module>()
      1 
      2 
----> 3 traning_neuralNetwork(x_test,x_train,y_test,y_train)

<ipython-input-3-92b45e11aa74> in traning_neuralNetwork(x_test, x_train, y_test, y_train)
     75         correct=tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
     76         accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct,'float'))
---> 77         print('accuracy',accuracy.eval({x : x_test,y : y_test}))
     78 
     79 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in eval(self, feed_dict, session)
    659 
    660     """
--> 661     return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
    662 
    663 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _eval_using_default_session(tensors, feed_dict, graph, session)
   5061                        "the tensor's graph is different from the session's "
   5062                        "graph.")
-> 5063   return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
   5064 
   5065 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    906     try:
    907       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 908                          run_metadata_ptr)
    909       if run_metadata:
    910         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1141     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1142       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1143                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1144     else:
   1145       results = []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1322     if handle is None:
   1323       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1324                            run_metadata)
   1325     else:
   1326       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1341         except KeyError:
   1342           pass
-> 1343       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1344 
   1345   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [55000] vs. [10000]
     [[Node: Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](ArgMax, ArgMax_1)]]

Caused by op 'Equal', defined at:
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2698, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2808, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-6ce6d479d3df>", line 3, in <module>
    traning_neuralNetwork(x_test,x_train,y_test,y_train)
  File "<ipython-input-3-92b45e11aa74>", line 75, in traning_neuralNetwork
    correct=tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 2455, in equal
    "Equal", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3306, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1669, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [55000] vs. [10000]
     [[Node: Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](ArgMax, ArgMax_1)]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [overcome Graphdef cannot be larger than 2GB in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349049/overcome-graphdef-cannot-be-larger-than-2gb-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Brother i am getting error at ** sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())** this point I am not printing images Will you please see the error traceback thank you!

Comment: I recognize the problem but I am facing dificulties to code it actually I am computing all the data (60000,28,28,1) at the same time thats why its going hard  ** def neural_network(x_train)** I should compute it batch by batch but feeling difficulties in coding part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data Matrix is a 4D array of size (48000 * 28 * 28 * 1) which is > 784,500.
As a side note, 32,928,000 is actually 28 * 28 * 42000, probably X_train matrix has a different shape. 
Could  you add print(X_train.shape[0]) and double check your matrix?

To solve your problem with GraphDef, have a look at this response:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36358913/4601719

`tf.initialize_all_variables` is depreciated, please use `tf.global_variables_initializer` as recommended here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initialize_all_variables

Comment: Actullay At fist i am reshaping my data. Now i try to run my code without reshaping my data now its working well X_train = **X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28,1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28,1)**  I am not doing this now

Comment: I am sorry, then what is the Error message you are getting now?

Comment: Here is my new problem now I fixed the previous one Thank you !