# Tensorflow graph bigger than 2GB

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, optimization, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to optimize a large tensorflow saved model, with 10MB saved_model.pb and 16GB variables. 
I tried to freeze my graph and do some further transforms. I've followed the steps https://medium.com/google-cloud/optimizing-tensorflow-models-for-serving-959080e9ddbf and stuck in frozen_model.
Since my saved model is large, I got a frozen graph of 4.5GB, which exceeded the protobuf limitation 2GB.

```
ValueError: Message tensorflow.GraphDef exceeds maximum protobuf size of 2GB: 4581102620
```

Because of this limitation, I couldn't do any further optimization like quantization or saved it back to saved model.
Any solutions?

Comment: I have a similar issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MariosV Not yet. I'm planning to split my graph into smaller ones, so that I can optimize.

Comment: @RoyHuang, Please refer this Stack Overflow Answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36358913/11530462 which provides tips to reduce the size of your Protobuf Size. Thanks!