# How to split a tensorflow graph into two parts and saved them to two saved_model?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I have a saved_model formatted tensorflow model with size of over 10GB. The computation graph consists of two parts, the upstream part is mainly sparse embedding matrix which accounts mostly for the large size, the downstream part is dnn. The first part is memory-intensive and it's better run on CPU, the second part contains ops that can be optimized on GPU. The two parts are divided by ops of `Gather` `SpaseSegmentSum` and `SparseSegmentMean`.

My question is how can I divide these two parts into two saved models, so that I can deploy them separately on CPU devices and GPU devices. What's the best practice on this topic? Is there any implementation example?

Comment: You can try exporting to onnx and manipulating the graphs there.

Comment: @dmedine Export to onnx would meet protobuf size limit in my case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59558170/tensorflow-graph-bigger-than-2gb